# What does "rep; nop;" mean in x86 assembly? Is it the same as the "pause" instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu, machine-code

- What does `rep; nop` mean?
- Is it the same as `pause` instruction?
- Is it the same as `rep nop` (without the semi-colon)?
- What's the difference to the simple `nop` instruction?
- Does it behave differently on AMD and Intel processors?
- (bonus) Where is the official documentation for these instructions?

---

#### Motivation for this question

After some discussion in the comments of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-compiler-optimization-on-a-small-piece-of-code), I realized that I don't know what `rep; nop;` means in x86 (or x86-64) assembly. And also I couldn't find a good explanation on the web.

I know that `rep` is a prefix that means *"repeat the next instruction `cx` times"* (or at least it was, in old 16-bit x86 assembly). According to this [summary table at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086.2F8088_instructions), it seems `rep` can only be used with `movs`, `stos`, `cmps`, `lods`, `scas` (but maybe this limitation was removed on newer processors). Thus, I would think `rep nop` (without semi-colon) would repeat a `nop` operation `cx` times.

However, after further searching, I got even more confused. It seems that `rep; nop` and `pause` [map to the exactly same opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589447/is-it-necessary-that-each-machine-code-can-only-map-to-one-assembly-code/2589462#2589462), and `pause` has a bit different behavior than just `nop`. Some [old mail from 2005](http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2005-March/005800.html) said different things:

- *"try not to burn too much power"*
- *"it is equivalent to 'nop' just with 2 byte encoding."*
- *"it is magic on intel. Its like 'nop but let the other HT sibling run'"*
- *"it is pause on intel and fast padding on Athlon"*

With these different opinions, I couldn't understand the correct meaning.

It's being used in Linux kernel (on both [i386](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/um/sys-i386/asm/processor.h#L53) and [x86_64](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/um/sys-x86_64/asm/processor.h#L20)), together with this comment: `/* REP NOP (PAUSE) is a good thing to insert into busy-wait loops. */` It is also [being used in BeRTOS](http://doc.bertos.org/2.6/attr_8h_source.html#l00096), with the same comment.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894078/pause-instruction-in-x86

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`rep; nop` is indeed the same as the `pause` instruction (opcode `F390`). It might be used for assemblers which don't support the `pause` instruction yet. On previous processors, this simply did nothing, just like `nop` but in two bytes. On new processors which support hyperthreading, it is used as a hint to the processor that you are executing a spinloop to increase performance. From [Intel's instruction reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-software-developers-manual-volume-2b-instruction-set-reference-m-u):

> Improves the performance of spin-wait loops. When executing a “spin-wait loop,” a Pentium 4 or Intel Xeon processor suffers a severe performance penalty when exiting the loop because it detects a possible memory order violation. The PAUSE instruction provides a hint to the processor that the code sequence is a spin-wait loop. The processor uses this hint to avoid the memory order violation in most situations, which greatly improves processor performance. For this reason, it is recommended that a PAUSE instruction be placed in all spin-wait loops.

Comment: Is *spin-wait loop* the same as *[busy-wait loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)*? Does this "improvement" only applies to hyperthreading processors? (and why?)

Comment: Yes, spin-wait loop is the same as busy-wait loop. The benefit also applies to CPUs that don't support hyper-threading. It can be thought of as limiting the number of (unnecessary) instructions in the pipeline (rather than attempting to do many iterations of the loop in parallel)

Comment: @Brendan, thanks! I didn't understand at all, until you said the thing about iterations of the loop in parallel.

Comment: @Brendan, Oh, now I get it! These modern processors are [superscalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar), and thus they will attempt to run multiple instructions at the same time. If this is a busy-wait loop, running more instructions won't make it faster, as it is just waiting for another condition.

Comment: @Denilson: Yes, hyperthreading-friendliness (or just power-saving without HT) is one big benefit, but the other is avoiding a memory-ordering mis-speculation when leaving the spin-loop.  Without `pause`, your spin-loop is effectively one pipeline-clear slower to notice the state-change of the memory location written by another core.

Answer (score 18):

`rep nop` = F3 90 = the encoding for `pause`, as well as how it decodes on older CPUs that don't support `pause`.

---

**Prefixes (other than `lock`) that don't apply to an instruction are ignored in practice by existing CPUs.**

The documentation says using `rep` with instructions it doesn't apply to is **"reserved and can cause unpredictable behaviour" because *future* CPUs might recognize it as part of some new instruction.**  Once they establish any specific new instruction encoding using `f3 xx`, they document how it runs on older CPUs.   (Yes, the x86 opcode space is so limited that they do crazy stuff like this, and yes it makes the decoders complicated.)

In this case, **it means you can use `pause` in spinloops without breaking backwards compat**.  Old CPUs that don't know about `pause` will decode it as a NOP with no harm done, as guaranteed by Intel's ISA ref manual [entry for `pause`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pause).  On new CPUs, you get the benefit of power-saving / HT friendliness, and [avoiding memory-ordering mis-speculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894078/pause-instruction-in-x86) when the memory you're spinning on does change and you leave the spin loop.

---

Links to Intel's manuals and tons of other good stuff on the [x86 tag wiki info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Another case of a meaningless `rep` prefix becoming a new instruction on new CPUs:  `lzcnt` is `F3 0F BD /r`.  On CPUs that don't support that instruction (missing the LZCNT feature flag in their CPUID), it decodes as `rep bsr`, which runs the same as `bsr`.  So on old CPUs, it produces `32 - expected_result`, and is undefined when the input was zero.

But `tzcnt` and `bsf` do the same thing with non-zero inputs, so compilers can and do use `tzcnt` even when it's not guaranteed that the target CPU will run it as `tzcnt`.  AMD CPUs have fast `tzcnt`, slow `bsf`, and on Intel they're both fast.  As long as it doesn't matter for correctness (you're not relying on flag-setting, or on leaving the destination unmodified behaviour in the input=0 case), having it decode as `tzcnt` on CPUs that support it is helpful.

---

One case of a meaningless `rep` prefix that will probably never decode differently: `rep ret` is used by default by gcc when targeting "generic" CPUs (i.e. not targetting a specific CPU with `-march` or `-mtune`, and not targetting AMD K8 or K10.)  It will be decades before anyone could make a CPU that decodes `rep ret` as anything other than `ret`, because it's present in most binaries in most Linux distros.  See  [What does `rep ret` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526361/what-does-rep-ret-mean)

Comment: The `rep` prefix was also used by Intel to add lock elision.

Comment: _Prefixes that don't apply to an instruction are ignored._ But it is mentioned that _Repeat Prefixes (`F2H` and `F3H`) Reserved and may result in unpredictable behavior_ in _Table 11-3. Effect of Prefixes on SSE, SSE2, and SSE3 Instructions_. So the prefix application is ignored for some of the instructions, not for all. So is this feature considered undocumented?

Comment: @St.Antario: They phrase it that way because *future* CPUs might recognize it as part of some new instruction.  On all real CPUs that's been the case, and once they establish an encoding using `f3 xx` they document how it runs on older CPUs.

Comment: _Prefixes (other than lock) that don't apply to an instruction are ignored in practice by existing CPUs._ It is documented that `rep movbe` causes `#UD`, so `rep` is not _always_ ignored. Even if it does not apply to an instruction in the sense as it is specified in the `REP/REPE/REPZ/REPNE/REPNZ` manual entry.

Comment: @St.Antario: Interesting!  In general though, for older instructions non-applicable prefixes are ignored.  When introducing a new instruction it's possible to add stricter rules if they choose.  IDK why they would choose that for this specific case.