# What happens when a rep-prefix is attached to a non string instruction?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, undefined-behavior

I tried to find out the speed difference between plain loops, `loop` loops and builtin `rep` loops. I wrote three programs to compare the behavior:

#### Program 1

```
_start: xor %ecx,%ecx
0:      not %ecx
        dec %ecx
        jnz 0b
        mov $1,%eax
        xor %ebx,%ebx
        int $0x80       # syscall 1: exit
```

#### Program 2

```
_start: xor %ecx,%ecx
        not %ecx
        loop .
        mov $1,%eax
        xor %ebx,%ebx
        int $0x80
```

#### Program 3

```
_start: xor %ecx,%ecx
        not %ecx
        rep nop # Do nothing but decrement ecx
        mov $1,%eax
        xor %ebx,%ebx
        int $0x80
```

It turned out the third program doesn't work as expected, and some recherche tells me, that `rep nop` aka `pause` does something completely unrelated.

*What are the `rep`, `repz` and `repnz` prefixes doing, when the instruction following them is not a string instruction?*

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086220/what-does-rep-nop-mean-in-x86-assembly

Comment: @ssg: Nope. The question you links just explains the behavior for `rep nop`. What happens for other instructions? Please try to read the entire question before voting to close.

Comment: It seems to me that your experiementation and research efforts all went into NOP, so I thought you wouldn't care about the rest since you didn't even care to test them?

Comment: @ssg There are many people whose main activity seems to be doing NOPs :-)

Comment: @ssg I just noticed `rep` doesn't works as expected with `nop` and also with `cmp $0,%ecx`. I am new to assembly so I wanted to ask before digging further.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends. `rep ret` is sometimes used to avoid bad performance of jumping directly to a `ret` on certain AMD processors. The `rep` (F3) and `repne` (F2) prefixes are also used as Mandatory Prefix for many SSE instructions (for example they change packed-single variants to scalar-singe or scalar-double variants). `pause` (spin lock hint) is an alias of `rep nop`. Some other new instructions use a "fake rep prefix" as well (`popcnt`, `crc32`, `vmxon`, etc). The "fake" or Mandatory Prefix comes before the optional REX prefix, so it can't be said to be part of the opcode, it really is a prefix.

Other operations generate an #UD if prefixed with a `rep`.

Comment: Also, on certain instructions it is taken to mean XACQUIRE/XRELEASE

Answer (score 4):

I'm just going to quote the [manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) here because I guess that specifies the only "official" behavior.

From Section 4.2 "REP/REPE/REPZ/REPNE/REPNZ - Repeat String Operation Prefix":

> The REP prefix can be added to the INS, OUTS, MOVS, LODS, and STOS
>   instructions, and the REPE, REPNE, REPZ, and REPNZ prefixes can be
>   added to the CMPS and SCAS instructions. (The REPZ and REPNZ prefixes
>   are synonymous forms of the REPE and REPNE prefixes, respectively.)
>   **The behavior of the REP prefix is undefined when used with non-string
>   instructions.**