# C99 gcc optimizes away while loop when I'd like it to generate an effecient lock

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, locking

When disassembling my program I noticed that;

```
while (!block->meta.lock);
```

would be compiled into;

```
0x0040167f <+111>:   jmp    0x40167f <gc_malloc+111>
```

Clearly this is a useless infinite loop. I'm using C99 so I can't make it volatile.

My current solution:

```
while (!block->meta.lock) {
    __sync_synchronize();
}
```

This generates a **lot** of extra assembly. What I'm really trying to generate is the equivalent of a `rep nop` lock;
See [What does "rep; nop;" mean in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086220/what-does-rep-nop-mean-in-x86-assembly)

How can I hint this to gcc?

Comment: What do you mean by “I'm using C99 so I can't make it volatile”?

Comment: volatile is in the C89 standard and it was used long before that.

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure I tried. I'll get back to you on that...

Comment: Assure that your `lock` field can be read atomically. Even if you use `volatile` this is not portable. Use other functions from `__sync` family (C11's atomics) to guarantee data coherence.

Comment: I don't think `__sync_synchronize` is the right one to use. What is your suggestion?

Comment: I made `block` a `volatile *` and I get the right assembly now. What isn't portable about `volatile` ? It seems to compile using `-pedantic`

Comment: `volatile` is 100% portable on every C and C++ compiler ever made...

Comment: @Lundin `volatile` is specified in C89 and subsequent specifications.  The previous 2 decades of C, being pre-standard, started without `volatile` and later developed it.   Confident `volatile` is neither in K&R 1st nor 2nd Ed and compilers existed that treated `volatile` not as a keyword but like any other identifier like 'foo'.  Certainly the `volatile` is ubiquitous now.

Comment: @chux What happened before 1989 is hardly relevant to this question... compilers made before C98/C90 were not standardized - essentially they didn't compile for the C language, but for their own home-brewed version of it. And even though K&R 2nd edition has plenty of errors, it is mostly compatible with the C90 standard. They certainly mentioned volatile, see A.8.2. To cite K&R 2nd ed: "There are no implementation-dependent semantics for volatile objects."