# C program spends 77% of the time in _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell

Tags: c, macos, profiling

I'm profiling some numerical code written in C (profiler is Instruments, compiler is `clang` on Mac OSX 10.11.6). As much as 77.3% of the running time is spent in `_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell`.

In the assembly output, the above function is called by `DYLD-STUB$$memcpy`. However, I have no `memcpy`'s in my C code (I do have some `malloc`'s though).

Going deeper, it seems that the assembly command `rep` is responsible for taking up so much time. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086220/what-does-rep-nop-mean-in-x86-assembly) post, it seems that `rep` is not doing anything useful. Why does the compiler insert it? And where do the `memcpy`'s come from?

I also tried compiling with `-g`, but then `_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell` is not gobbling up almost all of the time anymore.

Comment: Can you post the code? What kind of variance/standard deviation do your measurements have? How does the total runtime change with `-g`?

Comment: `rep` is doing the actual copying in memcpy.

Comment: Up for actually telling what you have done so far, and for finding out what was the problem.

Answer (score 9):

After a bit of more searching, I found the problem: I was passing a struct to a function, which gets copied each time, hence the `memcpy`.

I changed the function to accept a pointer to the struct, which sped up my code by a factor 5.

Comment: I'm guessing most people won't see this question or answer, since it's closed, but it was still helpful to me for a seemingly unrelated issue. +1 for reminding me of the importance of carefully passing pointers/structs. When programming in C, it's hard to be reminded of this too often! :-)